# short-story audio. A Cook (narrator) (sounded exactly like Paul Giamatti) on a ship traveling at light-speed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, audio-book, radio-play

A Cook (narrator) (sounded exactly like Paul Giamatti) on a ship traveling at light-speed. This is an experimental spaceship studying faster than light travel. He is the only one on board that he is aware of. Something weird happened when they hit light speed. Everyone vanished and navigation is not responding. Outside the ship is just blackness. He starts going crazy and imagines a woman or wife is there with him.

I found the short story on a free audio book app. I think it was once a radio-broadcast short story.

Comment: I don't know what book this is, but a quick search turned up the amusing fact that Paul Giamatti did do an audiobook of *A Scanner Darkly*.

Comment: yeah i saw that too

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.